# What is the most efficient way to serve huge chunks of binary data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I have an array consisting of 20 GB+ data. I want to serve that data via an API using `node.js`. My users will request a small slice of data (no more than a few kbs), at arbitrary position on the array. Moreover, that data is growing as time passes. Of course, I can't load 20GB of data into memory, so, what I need is an array class (with `read` and `push` operations) that stores data on disk instead of memory. Is there any such a thing?

Comment: a database maybe ? Like redis ?

Comment: @mh-cbon Redis was my first option, but I think it only provides lists, not arrays, right? So taking a small slice in the middle of a 20GB list would involve traversing 10GB. Also I'm not sure if it behaves well with such huge entries, does it?

Comment: read its doc. Then it s all up to you to decide how to use it, how t ostore the data. I don t think 20 gb is a big problem for redis, if used correclty.

Comment: I'd be really thankful if you could point to such thing because I read the whole doc on the provided datatypes and it says nothing that could be used on this case. Lists/hashes have the wrong properties, strings are up to 512 mb, etc...